# How to add two buttons with two handlers in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add cancel and restart buttons such that user clicking cancel button should stop the download of item data and restart should restart downloading item data.

**What i am trying to do?**

I have a list of items on start page. when i click on one item it takes me to another page and starts downloading item details. this downloading is shown with a progress bar to the user with a cancel button. This cancel button allows user to cancel the downloading of item data. When the user moves back to start page and click the same item...it shows the progress bar that is stopped. So here, it should show restart button instead of cancel button and clicking restart button should restart downloading item data.

**What i have tried so far?**

I have created a promise to cancel load_item_data request to the server (which basically downloads details related to item clicked). On clicking cancel button i resolve this promise and set load_cancel state to true. When this state is true i display the restart button and trigger load_item_data request to the server.

This works fine. Below is the code,

```
export default class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      load_cancel: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.item) {
      this.load_item_data();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (current_item_id != prevprops.item_id) {
      this.setState({ load_cancel: false }, this.load_item_data);
    }
  }

  load_cancel = () => {
    this.setState({ load_cancel: true }, this.load_promise());
    if (this.state.load_cancel) {
      this.load_item_data();
    }
  };

  load_item_data = () => {
    const props = this.props;
    this.file_download_status = {};
    if (this.on_item_changed) {
      this.on_item_changed();
    }
    if (this.load_cancel) {
      this.load_cancel();
    }

    const item_changed = new Promise(resolve => {
      this.on_item_changed = resolve;
    });
    const load_cancel = new Promise(resolve => {
      this.load_cancel = resolve;
    });
    const on_load_cancel = new Promsie(resolve => {
      this.load_cancel_promise = resolve;
    });
    const abort_loading = Promise.race([
      item_changed,
      on_load_cancel,
      this.unmount
    ]);

    item
      .load(props.item.id, gl, this.update_download_progress, abort_loading)
      .then(result => {
        this.files = result.files;
        this.setState({
          item_download_done: true
        });
        client.add_item_view(props.item.id, abort_loading);
      });
  };

  render() {
    <ChildComponent
      load_cancel_state={this.state.load_cancel}
      load_cancel={this.load_cancel}
    />;
  }
}

export default class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    <button onClick={this.props.load_cancel}>
      {this.props.load_cancel_state ? "restart" : "Cancel"}
    </button>;
  }
}
```

Here in the above code have created on_load_cancel promise withing load_item_data method. this resolves when user clicks cancel button and load_cancel_promise method called within load_cancel button.

**What i want to do?**

I want to have two buttons within childcomponent something like below,

```
{
  "some condition  when this button should be displayed" && (
    <button onClick={this.props.load_cancel}>Cancel</button>
  );
}
{
  "some condition when this button should be displayed" && (
    <button onClick="somemethod to handle load restart trigger">Restart</button>
  );
}
```

But i am not sure what conditions to use like what to be tracked when this cancel button clicked to stop downloading and when user comes back to same item display restart button.

Could someone help me solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and create a function in your parent component which saves the canceled item id in state (array), let's call it `cancelledItems` and next time when a user clicks on the item and goes to that screen. You can check that if item id is the array `cancelledItems` or not by passing that state to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with states, is better an aproach focused in what's happening than what have happened.
In the state, your main property could be a boolean to store if there are a download running. If you are going to allow one download at the time, must be something like that:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
      isDownloading: false,
    };
  }
```

And a render method like this:

```
render(){    
{
      {this.state.isDownloading &&
        <button onClick={this.props.load_cancel}>Cancel</button>
      );
      {!this.state.isDownloading &&
        <button onClick="somemethod to handle load restart trigger">Restart</button>
      );
}
```

And isDownloading must be updated with setState when the download changes.